# how to use c++ atomics

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

I'm confused about C++ atomic variables.  If I have an atomic x that I want to increment in one thread and read in another thread, can I do ++x or do I have to do  x.atomic_fetch_add(1).  In the reader thread, can I do something like cout << x;  or do I have to do cout << x.load().

If I have

```
int x;
atomic<bool> y;
```

then in thread one

```
if (!y)
{
   x = 23;
   y = true;
}
```

and in thread two

```
if (y)
{
   cout << x;
   y = false;
}
```

Is it guaranteed that thread two will see the value of (non atomic) x as 23.  If not, if I change the access to y to use load and store, will that make a difference?  Is it guaranteed that thread two will see the result of all non atomic operations that come before thread one sets y to true?

Can anyone suggest a book that explains these details clearly.

Comment: [This behaviour is documented](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) if you want to know more.

Comment: As a note, just because something's "atomic" does not mean you can't create race conditions with it as you've done here in your first example, if two threads could potentially assign to `y`. If you need to synchronize, consider using a mutex.

Comment: because you do `y = true` with more strong memory order than `memory_order_release` *All writes in the current thread are visible in other threads that acquire the same atomic variable*. and `if (y)` - read with also `memory_order_acquire` *All writes in other threads that release the same atomic variable are visible in the current thread* - so you read 23

Comment: from *Release-Acquire ordering* - *all memory writes (non-atomic and relaxed atomic) that happened-before the atomic store from the point of view of thread A, become visible side-effects in thread B. That is, once the atomic load is completed, thread B is guaranteed to see everything thread A wrote to memory.*

Comment: @RbMm: seems to be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @tadman: There’s still a difference between a race condition and a *data race* from concurrent non-atomic operations, which causes undefined behavior.

Comment: @tadman - mutex (or some another os level synchronization) need only in case we do several data modifications (say modify several variables) which by logic need do atomic. if we can to modification in atomic way - mutex not need here.

Comment: ok, so is it correct to say that the atomic write to y that I did, forces the compiler to generate a "memory barrier" instruction and it 1) prevents both the compiler and the hardware from moving memory assignments across the barrier 2) it forces a cache flush so that all threads see the updated data.  Does it also force the cache to be updated from external memory which might have been changed by other threads?  Is it correct that other caches can still be not up to date at this point but they will be updated if they do an atomic read?

Comment: @RbMm I'm talking about the code where `y` is tested, then later set. If you want that whole operation to be atomic you need to wrap it in a mutex or something similar. If there's only one thread that could write to `y` then this is irrelevant, but that's not entirely clear from the question.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize you have two questions to ask yourself with the variable y:

- Is the operation done properly, when variable is shared among threads?

This have to do with the atomicity of the operation, ie done all in one time. Atomicity provides you this guarantee

- Once the operation is done, do you want all threads to see the same order of operations?
  Quoting Anthony Williams in  [C++ Concurrency in Action](https://www.cplusplusconcurrencyinaction.com/)

> Even if the threads are running the same bit of code, they can disagree on the order of events because of operations in other threads **in the absence of specific ordering constraints**, because the different CPU caches and internal buffers can hold different values for the same memory

This has to do with [memory order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order)

As explained in the comments, the operations you do have sufficient level of memory order to guarantee what you would need.

For example assigment sequential consistency is memory_order_seq_cst, see link [link here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/atomic/operator=/)

Hope that helps

Comment: *immediately* is wrong word here. memory order (say Release-Acquire) guarantee only the some order of modifications and it view from another thread. but nothing can force *immediately* visible and what this is mean at all ?

Comment: ok, so should I replace immediatly with "in the next executions of the other threads?". I want to explain in detail what memory order means so that readers understand

Comment: again - what is "next executions" ? if we write to common memory, anyway this write will be visible from other threads. but when is undefined. using some memory order, hardware barriers - not make this faster or "immediately". this is separate different memory modifications. if we do 2 write to memory - `A` and `B` - in all case this will be visible to another threads (when undefined, but will be visible sometime). and in which order this will be visible - undefined (without memory ordering too). we can first write to A, but another thread can view modification of B but yet not view A

Comment: use memory order - let set concrete order of view - if we write to A then to B and another thread view our modification of B - it guarantee will be view modification of A too. but when another thread will view modification of B - this is always undefined. sometime. use memory order (hardware barriers) not make this faster, "immediately", or on "next executions"

Comment: ok thks for the explanation. I should then say instead of immediatly: you want to see the modification you have done and all the ones before, in order to be coherent ? (due to memory order).

Comment: *you want to see the modification you have done* - this always will be done auto. without use any atomic, any memory order operation. memory is common. and when one thread write to it, another threads will view this modification as soon as possible. but only some time. but if you want see all memory writes from thread #1 that happened-before the atomic store to `y` *after* you view this store of `y` you need acquire-release ordering. any memory order not force view of modification (it anyway became visible to all). it set order of view

Comment: memory order to force visibility of stores (this is auto) and not speed-up this (in any case this undefined, when another threads view this - every cpu have own time). memory order - set order of view modification. exactly order. nothing more

Comment: I can quote Anthony Williams regarding memory order and say "do you want all threads to see the same order of operations"? That would explain that modification in one thread is viewed exactly the same way in the others.